# What are the different coloured forces in "The Flash" (2014)...?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In Season 7 Episode 3 ("Mother") of *The Flash* TV series, we see that

> Iris gives the powers to Barry and gives him his speed back by charging the sphere.

In the process of doing so, we see that there are four different colors of lightning generated, which I assume are some kind of forces. I would like to identify what these forces are.

[image: Lightning colors generated when Iris gives Barry powers]
 <sub>*click to view a larger image*</sub>

Comment: This might help: [Why the different colors of speedster’s lightning?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145097/why-the-different-colors-of-speedster-s-lightning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The four different forces shown in the picture are -

- Speed Force
- Strength Force
- Sage Force
- Still Force

The yellow is Speed Force which has the form of Nora, the red is the Strength force which has the form of Fuerza, the blue one is the Sage force which has the form of Psych, and the Green one is Still force.

Answer (score 1):

The [Arrow Fandom Wiki](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Speed_Force#Lightning_coloration) has these color breakdowns

> - Yellow: Yellow lightning represents a pure or natural connection to the Speed Force. At the same time, as speedsters continue to develop their powers, such as Jay Garrick and Barry Allen, they eventually begin to exhibit a more orange coloring. Yellow is seen from Barry Allen, Jay Garrick, Jesse Wells, Wally West, Blitzkrieg, Barry Allen from Earth-90 and also formerly from Hunter Zolomon and Eliza Harmon.
> - Red: Red lightning is typically the result of a speedster having a
>   connection to an Artificial Speed Force, such as the Negative Speed
>   Force, which Eobard Thawne created at some point after recreating the
>   Flash's powers. Red lightning is seen in Eobard himself as well as
>   Edward Clariss. It is unknown why Clariss has red lightning but it is
>   possible that Clariss exercised his own hate to connect to the
>   Negative Speed Force, unknown to him. In addition, speedsters such as
>   Hunter Zolomon who are taken by Time Wraiths into the Speed Force also
>   have their lightning turned red.
> - Blue: Blue lightning generation is the result of an individual speedster who artificially enhances an existing Speed Force connection, or by artificially gaining access to the Speed Force through a strong enough dosage of the Velocity drug. While greatly increasing the user's speed, it also comes with lethal/life-threatening side-effects as seen with speedsters like Hunter Zolomon and Eliza Harmon, causing cellular degeneration, as well as a split personality in the case of the latter. Blue lightning could also be seen coming off of Godspeed due to the Velocity-9 he used to gain his speed.
> - White: White lightning is generated by the self-proclaimed "god of speed" Savitar, who is actually a time remnant of Barry Allen. It is a result of his lightning reflecting through his armor when he runs while wearing it. It is also generated by August Heart after using a combination of tachyons and Velocity-9.
> - Purple: Purple lightning has been produced by "Accelerated Man" and temporarily Iris West-Allen after Matthew Kim transferred Barry's powers to her. However, the reason for this lightning coloration is currently unknown.
> - Yellow and purple: Natural-born speedster Nora West-Allen emitted a combination of both yellow and purple lightning while running, though the reason for having multi-colored lightning is currently unknown. However, Iris has speculated that this may be due to genetics; Nora's father, Barry, produces yellow lightning when he runs, and when Barry's speed got transferred to Iris, Iris produced purple lightning when she ran.
> - Red and purple: After Nora ran into the Negative Speed Force, her yellow and purple lightning changed; her yellow lightning turned red while her purple lightning remained the same.[6]
> - Yellow and white: The Speed Force is seen with yellow and white lightning both in physical manifestations and in its purest form.
> - Dark: After Barry Allen became infected with black blood from Ramsey Rosso, his yellow lightning turned ghostly white with a dark aura.
> - Green and white: After the Speed Force became infected by the Spectre's energy boost, all of the lightning in the Speed Force was turned green and white.
> - Yellow and blue: After Barry took the Velocity X serum, his lightning briefly turned into blue and emitted the same sound Hunter Zolomon produced when he is running.